# How to grab data after wp user search is complete

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, users, query, wp-user-query

In the wp backend wp-admin > users.php there is a search field which we can use to search for particular users.

Let's say we search for a string '**test**' and it retrieves 3 users.

How can we grab the User ids of those results and display in a custom plugin? Is there a wp filter/action available that runs after the search is complete? I am familiar with `pre_user_query` and `pre_user_search` hooks but those run before the query is executed. But I think I am looking for a post query hook and I don't think there is any so in that case how can we do this?

Any help / guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a [`found_users_query` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/found_users_query/), but I can't think of a reason why you'd use this instead of just making your own call to [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/), which will deliver you the users that were found by your query.

Comment: I am not making any wp user query call but want to grab the results on this query if made someone else. For example, a site admin uses wp user search and I want to store the results in a log file.